# Exclude category on blog list page

Tags: posts, categories, filters, pre-get-posts, blog-page

I've got a site with a News page (archive for category 'news') and a separate Blog page. When I make a post for the News page I select the category 'news'. So, on the news page you only see the posts marked news, but on the blog page you can see all posts. What I would like to do is preferably show all posts EXCEPT the 'news' posts on the blog page. How do I do this?

```
<!--post start-->
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <!--post start-->
                    <div class="post">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="postimgbox">
                                <?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) { ?>
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <?php } else {

                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="post_meta">
                                <li class="post_date">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo get_the_time('M, d, Y') ?></li>
                                <li class="post_comment">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments.', '1 Comment.', '% Comments.'); ?>
                                </li>
                                <br />
                                <li class="posted_by">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                                </li>
                                <br />
                                <li class="post_category">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                                </li>
                                <br />
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post_content">
                            <h1 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </a></h1>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <a class="read_more" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e('Read More', 'infoway'); ?>&nbsp;<span class="button-tip"></span></a> </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End Post-->
```

Above is the code from blog.php, the php file I am trying to edit as it is the template for my blog page, (if it helps)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you for replying to my question but after trying to do something else I have managed to work out the answer, and what I believe to be the easiest and shortest answer. In the main loop for posting the posts you will see something along the lines of

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Before this code add in the following line,

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-4'); ?>
```

Where 4 is the category id. The - sign means 'not' and is similar to ! in C. This will mean all posts not in category ID 4 will be displayed on that page

Comment: That *might* work in your specific case, but, for your own sake, [*do not get into the habit of using* `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Answer (score 6):

From a plugin or your theme's *functions.php* file:

```
function wpse106861_mod_query( $query ) {
    /* are we on the blog page ? */
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        /* get ID of news category */
        $news_id = get_cat_ID( 'news' );
        /* exclude posts in new from query */
        $query->set( 'category__not_in' => array( $news_id ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse106861_mod_query' );
```

**Update**
As for the comment:
`is_home` should return true on any blog index page, regardless of whether that's a static page or your front page. You can check for the front page directly as well anyhow, by slightly altering the conditional:

```
if ( $query->is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query() )
```

**Related Reading**

- [`pre_get_posts` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)
- [`get_cat_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID)
- [`WP_Query` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: When this is put in functons.php I get a server error 500

Comment: Sorry - Can't see why it would. Are you certain that's not due to a mispaste?

Comment: Thanks, I've got it to stop returning error 500 with a syntax change. I am quite new to php, so how do I call the function in the blog.php template?

Comment: "blog.php" is not part of the regular [WP template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png). This appears rather theme-specific. It's possible, I guess, that you're not even modifying the main query here. You will have to include (the loop from) blog.php in your question. Both answers you got should work with a standard theme regardless of your Blog Index options.

Comment: I've posted the post posting loop from blog.php, you're right, it is from a theme called 'infoway'

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter. Do it like this:

```
function my_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array( 1, 1347 ) );  // where 1 and 1347 are IDs of excluded categories
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_exclude_category' );
```

PS. I assume that this Blog page is set as your posts page.

Comment: `category__not_in` parameter is better suit for this needs.

Comment: I've added this to functions.php but it doesn't work. Is this because the front page is set to show latest posts? As when I change it to be static in settings this code works. How do I make this work for a non-static front page